# OpenCV iOS strange behavior when applying CLAHE and THRESHOLD

Tags: ios, opencv

I have two methods: one for applying contrast-correction with CLAHE and one to binarize the image.

The order I call them is: 1. CLAHE, 2. Binarize

Both of them work great when I use only one. But when I call both in the order mentioned above, I get this picture:

[image: Result]

My code for CLAHE:

```
- (UIImage*)correctContrast:(UIImage*)image {

    cv::Mat cvImage = [self cvMatFromUIImage:image];

    cv::Mat grayImage;
    cv::cvtColor(cvImage, grayImage, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    cv::Mat contrastCorrectedImage;
    cv::Ptr<cv::CLAHE> clahe = cv::createCLAHE();
    clahe->setClipLimit(1.5);
    clahe->apply(grayImage, contrastCorrectedImage);

    UIImage* contrastCorrectedUIImage = [self UIImageFromCVMat:contrastCorrectedImage];

    return contrastCorrectedUIImage;
}
```

Binarizing the image:

```
- (UIImage*)binarize:(UIImage*)image {
    cv::Mat cvImage = [self cvMatFromUIImage:image];

    cv::Mat grayImage;
    cv::cvtColor(cvImage, grayImage, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    double MAX_THRESHOLD = 255;
    double THRESHOLD_VALUE = 165;
    cv::Mat binarizedImage;
    cv::threshold(grayImage, binarizedImage, THRESHOLD_VALUE, MAX_THRESHOLD, CV_THRESH_BINARY);

    UIImage* binarizedUIImage = [self UIImageFromCVMat:binarizedImage];

    return binarizedUIImage;
}
```

And how I use them:

```
let contrastImage = self.openCV.correctContrast(uiImageCropped!)
let binarizedImage = self.openCV.binarize(contrastImage!)
self.image = binarizedImage
```

**Edit**
The input image is just a normal businesscard.

Comment: It would be really useful if you also showed the input image... Kinda hard to guess what it looked like based on the result.

Comment: The input image is just a normal businesscard.